# Cannot push to bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have repeated following procedure for many times:

`ssh-keygen`

eval `ssh-agent`

Agent pid is printed

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

I enter my passphrase, and I see phrase "Identity added: ..."

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

I copy my public SSH and print it to https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

I see this text:

```
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

But then, when I print

`git push -u origin master`

I get this message:

```
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
```

What wrong am I doing & how to deal with it?

Comment: Maybe the repository doesn't exist?

Comment: It might be nice if Bitbucket said *who* they think you're authenticated as. (If they do and you snipped it, use that, if not, ask someone at Bitbucket how to find out.) Then just make sure you—by which I mean "the person Bitbucket think you are", since they may think you're some other guy named Pavel, or maybe someone named Fred or Vivek or something—do in fact have the necessary access to that repository. Make sure you have not made any typos in the path.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having the exact same issue while the same setup worked a few days ago...

Answer (score 2):

`git push --set-upstream origin master` because your origin does not know if, the branch you're pushing to is `master` or not.